# Maximum call stack size exceeded - coming from dash_table

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I get the the “Maximum call stack size exceeded” error when I want to fix headers with table scrolling and I am unable to reproduce it or identify any sort of pattern that causes this.

```
(This error originated from the built-in JavaScript code that runs Dash apps. Click to see the full stack trace or open your browser's console.)
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at [Symbol.replace] (<anonymous>)
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at lx.trim (http://X/_dash-component-suites/dash/deps/polyfill@7.v2_6_1m1659465116.12.1.min.js:1:34198)
    at parseInt (http://X/_dash-component-suites/dash/deps/polyfill@7.v2_6_1m1659465116.12.1.min.js:1:28885)
    at u.handleResize (http://X/_dash-component-suites/dash/dash_table/async-table.js:2:312632)
    at u.handleResize (http://X/_dash-component-suites/dash/dash_table/async-table.js:2:312697)
    at u.handleResize (http://X/_dash-component-suites/dash/dash_table/async-table.js:2:312697)
    at u.handleResize (http://X/_dash-component-suites/dash/dash_table/async-table.js:2:312697)
    at u.handleResize (http://X/_dash-component-suites/dash/dash_table/async-table.js:2:312697)
    at u.handleResize (http://X/_dash-component-suites/dash/dash_table/async-table.js:2:312697)
```

my table code:

```
table = dash_table.DataTable(
    columns=[
        {"name": col, "id": col, "selectable": True} for col in df.columns
    ],
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    id='datatable-interact',
    # page_current=0,
    # page_action='native',
    # page_size=30,
    # fixed_rows={'headers': True},
    style_table=table_style,
    style_header=header_style,
    style_cell=cell_style,
)
```

styling:

```
tab_style = {'margin-right': '10px', 'margin-left': '20px'}
table_style = {'overflowX': 'auto',  'position': 'relative', 'min-width': '1000px', 'height': 400,
               'display': 'inline-block', 'justify-content': 'center', 'left': '50%', 'transform': 'translateX(-50%)',
               'overflowY': 'scroll'}  #'height': 'auto'
header_style = {'backgroundColor': 'grey', 'color': 'black', 'fontWeight': 'bold', 'textAlign': 'center',
                'font-family': 'Arial, sans-serif', 'font-size': '14px', 'height': '35px', 'width': 'auto'}
cell_style = {'whiteSpace': 'normal', 'overflow': 'hidden', 'textOverflow': 'ellipsis', 'textAlign': 'right',
              'cursor': 'pointer', 'padding': '6px', 'font-family': 'Arial, sans-serif', 'font-size': '14px',
              'text-decoration': 'none !important', 'width': 'auto'}
```

Please, help me to decide this problem

Comment: I also had the same problem, and what seemed to resolve it in my case was to change the parent div's style. I used to have it `style={"display": "flex"}` and once I removed it, I stopped having this issue. This issue only came up when I tried to filter the HTML table using `filter_action="native"`.